# Invoke the image directly from website to our app

Tags: android

I want to use the image directly from website. I did not place that image in drawable folder. For this purpose what can I do?

Please, give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a function that creates a `Drawable` from an image url, look below:

```
private Drawable downloadThumbnails(String url) {
    Drawable d = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src_from_stream");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

then use it like this:

```
Drawable img = downloadThumbnails("http://yoururl.com/image.png");
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://an.url.com/lovely_cats.png").into(imageView);
```

It has a lot of usefull functions that allows you to:

- crop the image
- resize the image
- rotate the image
- fit an image into the target view
- replace not downloaded file with local placeholder

an even more - mostly in a single line (or call).